# Sorted TStringList error - Operation not allowed on sorted list

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am getting the following error - "Operation not allowed on sorted list"

```
Idx:= Customers.IndexOfName(ListView1.Selected.Caption);
Customers[idx]:= Edit1.Text + '=' + Edit2.Text + ',' + Edit3.Text //error occurs here
```

Is there any way around this? other than writng my own routine to get the index value

thanx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing your own routine to *get* the index value obviously won't help since that's not where the problem lies. You're not allowed to directly modify an element of a sorted list because doing so might invalidate the sort order.

Delete the item from the list and insert the new item.

```
Customers.Delete(idx);
Customers.Add(Edit1.Text + '=' + Edit2.Text + ',' + Edit3.Text);
```

Or, set `Sorted := False`.